# How to configure an Apache config on Windows with different php Version for different virtual hosts

Tags: php, windows, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am testing different syntax in the httpd.config of Apache 2.4 / Windows 10 to have different php Versions for different virtual hosts.
Domain1 should have PHP 8.1 and Domain2 should run with PHP 7.4.
This is one of my tests:
Sometimes with the line

```
LoadModule php7_module "C:/amp/php74/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

sometimes without it.
I get different errors.
This version works for Domain 1 but not for Domain 2 which needs 7.4.

```
#LoadModule php7_module "C:/amp/php74/php7apache2_4.dll"
LoadModule php_module "C:/amp/php8/php8apache2_4.dll"

<IfModule php_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    PHPIniDir "C:/amp/php8"
</IfModule>


<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "D:/wwwroot"
<Directory "D:/wwwroot">
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName domain1.localhost
DocumentRoot "D:/wwwroot/domain1/web"
ErrorLog "logs/domain1-error.log"
<Directory "D:/wwwroot/domain1/web">
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName domain2.localhost
DocumentRoot "D:/wwwroot/domain2"
ErrorLog "logs/domain2-error.log"
<Directory "D:/wwwroot/domain2">
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
</Directory> 

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
        Action application/x-httpd-php "C:/amp/php74/php-cgi.exe"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

What would be the right syntax?

Comment: You cannot directly operate two different versions of php _inside_ an apache http server. What you can do is operate different versions in different processes that can be reached by the apache server. For example you could run one version as an apache module, the other one in a fpm server. Then all you'd have to do is configure the apache server as a frontend / procy server to pass thru the requests meant to be processed by the background fpm service. That is pretty common, actually.

Comment: Try laragon. Very simple to change between php versions if you're on a local development environment

Comment: There can only be one `mod_php` loaded. One possibility is to use some other SAPI, e.g. [mod_fcgid](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/). You'll need to migrate `php_flag` and `php_values` Apache directives (if any) into `.user.ini` files (with the appropriate syntax) but, other than that, you won't notice much of a difference.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, you can keep `mod_php` and configure one or more virtual host to use `mod_fcgid` (a single instance of this module can cope with as any PHP versions as you need). Also, the benefit over other solutions is that you don't need to _switch_, each project will use the PHP version it needs.

Comment: thanks for you comments. 
Ok, i understand, that there is no simple solution. 
Perhaps i will try one of the solutions here. But at the moment i will rename my httpd.conf-Versions for php 8 or 7 every time i need. It is only in rare situations, that i still need php 7.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` is bound to one specific PHP version and only one instance can be loaded, so there's no way to have different PHP versions at the same time. You can switch between versions if you change the `LoadModule` directive and restart Apache (there're third-party bundles that script this) or you can install another copy of Apache listening to a different IP+port combination.

Another alternative it to install a different SAPI module side to side (or replacing) `mod_php`, such as [mod_fcgid](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/). For that:

1. Download as many PHP versions as you need and install them in different directories.
2. Get the module if you don't have it already. [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) provides Windows binaries.
3. Load the module with whatever system-wide defaults you see fit:

   ```
   LoadModule fcgid_module C:/path/to/mod_fcgid.so
   FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/PHP74"
   FcgidWrapper "C:/PHP74/php-cgi.exe" .php
   ```
4. For each virtual host where you want a different PHP version, replace `mod_php` with `mod_fcgid`:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName legacy.example.com
       # ...

       Options +ExecCGI
       <FilesMatch \.php$>
           SetHandler fcgid-script
       </FilesMatch>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   If you dropped `mod_php` entirely you can also do this:

   ```
   Options +ExecCGI
   <FilesMatch \.php$>
       AddHandler fcgid-script .php
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
5. If you need yet another PHP version, set a different interpreter inside the required virtual host:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName latest.example.com
       # ...

       Options +ExecCGI
       <FilesMatch \.php$>
           SetHandler fcgid-script
       </FilesMatch>
       FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/PHP83"
       FcgidWrapper "C:/PHP83/php-cgi.exe" .php
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. If you're setting PHP directives in `.htaccess` or other Apache settings files (`php_flag`, `php_value`, etc.), you'll need to migrate these into into `.user.ini` files (with the appropriate syntax).

The benefit over other solutions is that you don't need to *switch*, all projects will use the PHP version they need, simultaneously.

Note: this is written with Windows in mind. On Linux, you'll probably prefer [php-fpm](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php).